# How to access data from a structure pointer within a structure

Tags: c

I am trying to print the x value for newBall, but don't understand how to access it. Can someone help me out? I have a pointer to a struct Ball within the struct AllBalls. I get a compile error saying x is not a member of a structure.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>


    struct Ball {
        char id;
        double x;
        double y;
        double Vx;
        double Vy;
    };

    struct AllBalls {
        int count; 
        struct Ball *ballPtr; 
    };

int main(void) 
{   
    int index = 1; 
    struct AllBalls list = {0, NULL};
    struct Ball newBall;
    double x, y, Vx, Vy;
    int input;

    printf("Enter input: ");
    input = scanf("%lf %lf %lf %lf", &x, &y, &Vx, &Vy);
    list.count++;
    list.ballPtr = &newBall;
    newBall.id = 64 + list.count;
    newBall.x = x;
    newBall.y = y;
    newBall.Vx = Vx;
    newBall.Vy = Vy;
    printf("%lf", *(list.ballPtr).x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line near the end:

```
 printf("%lf", *(list.ballPtr).x);
```

The member selection operator `.` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.  So the compiler thinks you're trying to access a pointer as a struct.  You can fix this by moving the parenthesis:

```
 printf("%lf", (*list.ballPtr).x);
```

Or by using the pointer to member operator `->` instead:

```
 printf("%lf", list.ballPtr->x);
```